# Unable to run WCF Service Application with target machine actively refusing 127.0.0.1:24345

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, iis-6

I have a visual studio 2010 solution with a WCF Service Application project. A second client project in WPF uses the WCF Service Application. When run in the debugger, *all appears to work correctly.*

Using ClickOnce from the top menu bar, the startup project, the WPF client, is then published to //localhost/deploy and setup.exe is run. Everything seems to install and the start menu is updated with the program name.

However, when the WPF program is executed, I get:

*"System.Net.WebException System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine active refused it 127.0.0.1:24345"*

I am using Windows 7 and verified through "turn windows features on or off" that all IIS modules are installed.

What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Below is the Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And the app.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>

 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>


 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:24324/DataService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService" contract="DataService.INovaDataService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you checked that your Wcf Service instance is running on specified port, you have to seperately deploy your wcf application or neeed to use self hosting mode of your wcf application, issue is due to that you havenot deployed or wcf any  where.

Comment: @AshokRathod Hi. As far as I can tell, the Wcf Application Service project is being (or supposed to be) hosted in IIS--and no response is obtained when localhost:24324 is typed in the browser address bar.

Comment: @AshokRathod How do you startup self-hosting mode for the WCF Application Service?

Comment: when you run your setup it didnt do it automatically, you neeed to manually host your WCF application , or first you neeed to set self hosting for wcf service.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AshokRathod Thanks. I think I'm brain dead. A working example would be great!

Comment: @AshokRathod I don't know if it is relevant, but I created the project as a WCF Application Service--which I thought automatically calls the IIS service. Am I wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62941/discussion-between-ashok-rathod-and-alan-wayne).